# how do I change initWithNibName for storyboard use?

Tags: ios, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am using the following tutorial from ray 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app

im getting everything to work except for the detail view to populate from didselectrow

This is what he has

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.details == nil) {

        self.details = [[[FailedBanksDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FailedBanksDetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];        
    }
    FailedBankInfo *info = [_failedBankInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _details.uniqueId = info.uniqueId;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_details animated:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"testID" sender:self.view];
}
```

however it is not working with storyboards

Can someone please help me, I searched everywhere for an answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

Currently your using code for bob the NIB and the storyboard. Choose 1 and stick with it. If you go with storyboard, just perform the segue then handle the `prepareForSegue:sender:` to configure the destination view controller.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
self.details = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FailedBanksDetailViewController"];
```

Where `FailedBanksDetailViewController` is the `identifier` for the view controller in your main storyboard.

And since you are using http://www.raywenderlich.com you can take a look [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) for a storyboard example.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

1. You could supply the scene you're transitioning to with a "storyboard id" (you do this in Interface Builder) and then use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` instead of `initWithNibName`.
2. If you use cell prototypes in your storyboard, you don't need a `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method at all, and instead just add a segue from your cell prototype to the next scene. You then write a `prepareForSegue` method in which you pass the `uniqueId` to the next scene.

   That `prepareForSegue` might look like:

   ```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
       if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailsSegue"])
       {
           NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
           FailedBankInfo *info = [_failedBankInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           [(FailedBanksDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setUniqueId:info.uniqueId];
       }
   }
   ```

   Obviously, replace `DetailsSegue` with whatever name you supply for your segue's storyboard id.

Comment: Thank you so much! this started to work for me however when I imput the code i get an error
Property 'tableView' not found on object of type 'locationViewController *'
Any ideas?

Comment: This happens when i try using a table view on top of a viewcontroller if that helps

Comment: @Thomasrocks If you're following along in that tutorial, `FailedBanksListViewController` is a `UITableViewController` subclass, which provides it a `tableView` property. I don't know what this `locationViewController` class is. Did you just add a tableview to a `UIViewController` subclass? If so, what is the `IBOutlet` for the table view? Just replace `self.tableView` with the `IBOutlet` for your tableview.

Comment: I added a table view on top of a view because i was trying to incorporate this into another app as a subview.
I dont think i added a iboutlet for the table tho. I think i confused myself. How would i do that?
Thank you very much for your replys